# On the importance of the Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem.

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory, self-learning, riesz-representation-theorem

I am following big Rudin and I have arrived at the representation theorem.
Before doing the full long proof I would like to know what results are based on this theorem that for completeness I state below:

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space. For any positive linear functional $\psi$ on $C_c(X)$, there is a unique regular Borel measure $μ$ on $X $such that:

$$
    \psi(f) = \int_X f(x) \, d \mu(x) \quad 
$$

for all f in Cc(X).

(Rudin proves it in a more general setting ).

I apologize if I should already understand why this is important and what results are based on this but in my defence I am fairly new to measure theory.

Comment: I think Rudim uses this theorem to construct the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb{R}^d$. More generally, the theorem can be used to show existence of the Haar measure on a LCH group. It is also used (IIRC) for the proof of the spectral theorem in infinite dimensions.